# Sensibly integrating wildmenu options with the airline plugin

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vim-airline

I have used the following options in my `*.vimrc` to get the command completion:

```
" -- Show matching options in the airline
set wildmenu
set wildmode=list:longest,full
set showcmd
" --
```

When used alongside the [*airline*](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) plug-in, the results are odd:

- I'm getting the desired single-line bar with all the options
- Additionally, all options are listed again above, as shown:

[image]

*How can I only keep the single line scroll bar with all the matching options?*

Answer (score 2):

What you have in that screenshot is in line with the value you set for `wildmode` so… Vim does exactly what you tell it to do. If you want another behavior you will have to experiment with the different possible values.

From `:help 'wildmode'`:

```
"list:longest"  When more than one match, list all matches and
                complete till longest common string.
```

Basically, you will get that unwanted (but explicitly requested) columnar list as long as you keep `list` in your `'wildmode'`.

IMO, the only usable value is `full`.

Also, this question has nothing to do with vim-airline.

Answer (score 0):

[@romainl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546861/romainl), thanks for the contribution. For the record, the desired behaviour can be obtained with use of the following settings:

```
 " -- Command menu in one line
 set wildmenu
 set wildmode=full
 " --
```

[image: all comands shwoing in one line]